# Use perf inside a docker container without --privileged

Tags: linux, docker, privileges, perf

I am trying to use the perf tool inside a Docker container to record a given command.

`kernel.perf_event_paranoid` is set to 1, but the container behaves just as if it were 2, when I don't put the `--privileged` flag.

I could use `--privileged`, but the code I am running perf on is not trusted and if I am OK with taking a slight security risk by allowing perf tool, giving privileged rights on the container seems a different level of risk.

Is there any other way to use perf inside the container?

```
~$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   7392c3b/17.03.1-ce
 Built:        Tue May 30 17:59:44 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   7392c3b/17.03.1-ce
 Built:        Tue May 30 17:59:44 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false

~$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid
1
~$ perf record ./my-executable
perf_event_open(..., PERF_FLAG_FD_CLOEXEC) failed with unexpected error 1 (Operation not permitted)
perf_event_open(..., 0) failed unexpectedly with error 1 (Operation not permitted)
Error:
You may not have permission to collect stats.
Consider tweaking /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid:
 -1 - Not paranoid at all
  0 - Disallow raw tracepoint access for unpriv
  1 - Disallow cpu events for unpriv
  2 - Disallow kernel profiling for unpriv
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

After some research, the problem is not with the `perf_event_paranoid`, but with the fact that `perf_event_open` (syscall) has been blacklisted in docker:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/ "Docker v17.06: Seccomp security profiles for Docker"

> Significant syscalls blocked by the default profile
>
> `perf_event_open` Tracing/profiling syscall, which could leak a lot of information on the host.

My first work-around for this is to have a script that downloads the official seccomp file https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/profiles/seccomp/default.json, and adds `perf_event_open` to the list of white-listed syscalls.

I then start docker with `--security-opt seccomp=my-seccomp.json`

Comment: Can I update this somehow in a running container? Or atleast inject it through docker-compose?

Comment: I found this question & answer when looking for a solution to a specific problem of running Async Profiler in a container. This section in their README is related: https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler#profiling-java-in-a-container

Answer (score 1):

Run docker with `--cap-add SYS_ADMIN`

Comment: Doesn't `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` allow a *lot* of other privileges?  https://lwn.net/Articles/486306/  Does that make it possible for code inside docker to take over the host kernel by loading modules?